# Adding an animating circle to my UITableViewCell AccesoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

I'd like to display an animating circle in my UITableViewCell. I've gotten the following code to work for self.view, but when I try to add it to cell.accessoryview it never draws. Anybody have any ideas on why it's not showing up?

```
- (void)makeCircleAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [_permanentSoundTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

    // Set up the shape of the circle
    int radius = 10;
    circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // Make a circular shape
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                             cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    // Center the shape in self.view
    circle.position = CGPointMake(cell.frame.size.width-10,cell.frame.size.height-5);

    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    UIColor *transparentBlack = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f green:250.0f blue:250.0f alpha:.5];

    circle.strokeColor = transparentBlack.CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 5;


    // Add to parent layer
    [cell.accessoryView.layer addSublayer:circle];

    // Configure animation
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 8.0; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;   // Remain stroked after the animation..

    // Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

    // Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    // Add the animation to the circle
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: try out with subclassing the cell

Comment: @Shan I really shouldn't need to subclass the cell. Can you provide any other advice?

Comment: by subclassing the cell u can get more flexibility over the cell, for animations within the cell i prefer subclassing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your animation layer inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and make sure `accessoryView` of the cell is not `nil`. If it's `nil`, then add empty `UIView` with your animation layer's size, and then adding the layer. Good Luck!

Comment: but I want to begin the animation when the user presses on the cell, so is there a way to access the sublayer once it's been placed inside the accessoryview? Thanks for your response

Comment: Yes, you can get your layer by accessing accessoryView layer's `sublayers` method. Or, as @Shan suggested, subclass `UITableViewCell`, and add proper methods for animating the layer, it's not that hard to implement.

Comment: actually quick question: when implementing a custom cell do I need to create a new xib or can I reference the prototype cell in storyboard?

Comment: I doon't really know that :) I don't use storyboard things :)